# How to get result of two select join statement with one query instead

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to retrieve table rows (of tables: `receipt` and `invoice`) by date column of both tables with a single select query.

invoice columns are:

```
| Bill_number | bill_date | amount_paid | total_amount | customer_id |
```

receipt columns are:

```
| Bill_number | bill_date | total_amount | customer_id |
```

I can retrieve expected data (date of specific) with `select` and `join` clause from one table at a time , but I could not find out how to retrieve/search a particular date in row of both tables in one single query.

Queries work fine individually:

```
SELECT receipt.*, customer.customer_name
FROM receipt
INNER JOIN customer ON receipt.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE receipt.bill_date = '2016-06-24'  

SELECT invoice.*, customer.customer_name
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN customer ON invoice.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE invoice.bill_date = '2016-06-24'
```

Expected result:

```
|bill_number| bill_date |amount_paid| total_amount |customer_id| customer_name |
       1     2016-06-24      20          20             1            John     <-- invoice table
       1     2016-06-24                  20             1            John     <-- receipt table
```

Thanks a lot .

Comment: Another result set with no data set. Are we psychic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `UNION`. If the two tables don't match exactly, you might have to define missing columns (for instance the `amount_paid` column in this situation):

```
(SELECT bill_number, bill_date, amount_paid, total_amount, customer.customer_id, customer_name
 FROM receipt
 INNER JOIN customer ON receipt.customer_id = customer.customer_id
 WHERE receipt.bill_date = '2016-06-24')
UNION
(SELECT bill_number, bill_date, NULL AS amount_paid, total_amount, customer.customer_id, customer_name
 FROM invoice
 INNER JOIN customer ON invoice.customer_id = customer.customer_id
 WHERE invoice.bill_date = '2016-06-24')
```

Here is the [link to the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Comment: Thanks, but how can i retrieve different number of columns with union i need all those columns.

Comment: for unmatched columns  or missing column, `IF(bill_number != 0,0, 0)as amount_paid` , can be used to virtually create that column.